# IE strict mode flicker on activex controls

Tags: activex, flicker, quirks-mode, strict-mode

I have a web page containing (amongst other things) several activex controls embedded in it.  It's only ever rendered in IE, and it's in strict mode.  If I highlight any text in the page (or rollover an image with an onmouseover event to change it's image or whatever), the controls all flicker horribly.

If I change the page to quirks mode, the flicker vanishes.  I've done extensive searches looking for a solution, and found lot's of stuff about how IE 6 was broken and weird, but this is happening in IE 7 and 8.

So, any ideas on what I can do to fix and/or diagnose this?

Comment: do you have a URL we can peek at? without some context of the DOM around it it is very hard to diagnose.

Comment: Not easily I'm afraid.  It's all designed to run locally, and there is no way I could give you access to the actual activex controls or anything.  I'll see if there is something I can post as s minimal example

Comment: OK, the following html is enough to show the problem (on my machine where I have the control of course :)

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
   <body>
      <object classid="CLSID:84C7B55D-8747-48f9-A578-2AFB76F61C5E"></object>
      Have the participant insert the mouthpiece and attach a nose clip.
   </body>
</html>

All I need to do is click on the text and run the mouse over it, highlighting it, and the control flickers.

Probably not very helpful I know...

Comment: oops.  I'll stick it into a proper reply, I think

Comment: OK, I've tracked it down further...  If I override OnPaintBackground for the control, the flickering goes away.  It now isn't rendering right because we were relying on the OnPaintBackground behaviour being there.  So my best guess for a proper fix is to figure out where and why strict-mode IE is invalidating the page on text select and tell it not to.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> If I override OnPaintBackground for the control, the flickering goes away.